# create a php file in vagrant and have the host OS browser display the result

Tags: php, macos, apache, vagrant

In my mac terminal I typed:

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
```

after which my command prompt is inside vagrant and displays:

```
vagrant@zero-to-slim:~$
```

after which I type:

```
vagrant@zero-to-slim:~$ cd /vagrant
```

where I have created a php file (called hello.php)

```
<?php
echo "Hello World from inside vagrant!!";
?>
```

When I go to firefox and type /var/www I can see the contents of the directory:

(i) a folder named zero-to-slim.dev

(ii) index.html

(iii) hello.php

I want to enter (in my browser) localhost/hello.php and be able to see "Hello World from inside vagrant!!", which is clearly not happening. How do I make that happen? FYI, just typing localhost in firefox displays: "It Works!" I'm not using PuPHET or anything, just LAMP.

Also I think the problem is I have to direct my host OS Apache to look at some shared folder to render .php files. No idea how to do that either (new to LAMP dev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSX comes with PHP pre-installed but not configured.  You have to do that yourself.

According to [Using the bundled PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.bundled.php) on PHP.net:

> PHP has come standard with Macs since OS X version 10.0.0. Enabling PHP with the default web server requires uncommenting a few lines in the Apache configuration file `httpd.conf` whereas the CGI and/or CLI are enabled by default (easily accessible via the Terminal program).

and it goes on to say that you *start* by uncommenting the lines mentioning php in `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, e.g.,

```
# LoadModule php5_module libexec/httpd/libphp5.so

# AddModule mod_php5.c
```

and restart Apache.